# Spark gets 'The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records'

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have `access` and `secret` of s3, it works fine in Python3+boto3 and Java respectively, but when I use the `access` and `secret` in Spark shell or submit a `xx.jar` coded by Scala, it throws Exception below

> Spark 2.4.5,Hadoop 2.7.2, Java8,  Scala 2.11.x

in SPARK_HOME/jars

> aws-java-sdk-1.12.183.jar 、aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.492.jar、aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.447.jar

```sh
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 Error Message. -- ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>MYACCESS</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>MYREQUEST</RequestId><HostId>xxxxxxxxx</HostId></Error>
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.get(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.retrieveINode(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
```

python demo(not pyspark)- works fine

```py
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
s3_cli = boto3.client('s3', 
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4',
    s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}), use_ssl=False,
    endpoint_url='MY_ENDPOINT_URL',
    aws_secret_access_key='MY_SECRET',
    aws_access_key_id='MY_ACCESS')

with open('txtFromS3.txt', 'wb') as data:
  s3_cli.download_fileobj('MY_BUCKET', 'myTxtOnS3.txt', data)
```

scala(in spark-shell or spark-submit --class xx xxx.jar):  EXCEPTION

```scala
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.endpoint", "MY_ENDPOINT")# s3a、
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", 'MY_ACCESS');
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", 'MY_SECRET');

val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://MY_BUCKET/myTxtOnS3.txt")
println(rdd.count())
```

have tried almost all the solutions I could find including
`fs.s3a.xxx`、`fs.s3n.xxxx`

`fs.s3X.access.key`、`fs.s3X.secret.key`, X is a、n、nothing

`sc.textFile("s3X://MY_ACCESS:MY_SECRET/MY_BUCKET@myTxtOnS3.txt")`

Comment: that jets3t on the stack trace implies its a *really* old version of hadoop underneath spark, and things may not work any more. switch a modern version of the hadoop binaries (hadoop-3.3.2 ideally) and go through the s3a connector

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The cause is that the node/client on which I run spark 2.4.5 is deployed with Hadoop 2.7, but nodes on cluster are Hadoop 3.2+. Thats why all the attempts failed

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this Exception,

**Cause**：
My client node has `spark 2.4.5` + `Hadoop 2.7`, but nodes on cluster are `Hadoop 3.2.0`, So the main cause is the Hadoop version not matched.

Event though I replace the `hadoop-aws-2.7.2.jar` with `hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar`, still not woks. Exceptions are 40X: InvalidAccesssKey、Permission denied, etc.

**Solution**

- upgrade `Hadoop 2.7` on client node to `Hadoop 3.2.0`
- `aws-java-sdk-1.12.183.jar` and `hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar`
- `fs.s3a.endpoint`、`fs.s3a.access.key`、`fs.s3a.secret.key` (not s3 and awsSecretAccessKey for me)